# How to redirect user to original page after login via IdentityServer3

Tags: openid, identityserver3

I have very similar requirement described in this question [Get redirect link from client in IdentityServer3 login page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39487444/get-redirect-link-from-client-in-identityserver3-login-page). 
When user, being not logged in, opens any specific client application page, for example, from bookmarks, or when session expired, and user refreshes specific page or does some action, then s/he is redirected to login page of IdentityServer3.

But I am confused how to implement that original page is *remembered*, and user is redirected back to originally opened application page and not to the application root (configured as static redirect url in both idsrv3 and OIDC middleware).

Could someone please guide me if it is possible and how to do that?

My assumptions so far:

1. Originally opened page should be somehow passed to idsrv3 login page, for example, as some redirect url query string parameter. And probably OIDC middleware should be adjusted/extended in order to do that?
2. Idsrv3 should support redirect url or it should be possible somehow to configure/extend it to support redirect url.
3. If idsrv3  doesn't not support such redirect fully, then might need to implement custom redirectUri validator to pass redirectUri validation (this is the only clear part).
   Could

My client application based on Angular 1.X, WebApi 2, OWIN and with three middleware configured: UseCookieAuthentication, UserIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication and UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication,  pretty *standard* setup. And application is a fork of IdentityManager with some modifications.

Answer (score 3):

So, I believe you have two scenarios:

1. The user is on anonymous-allowed page, and clicks login.
2. The user navigates/or enters a URL that's in need of auth.

### 1 Challenge

If you want to challenge: (the user is on a page not in need of auth, and clicks a login button), you can pass the current page to the OIDC middleware like this:

```
public void ActionResult Login(string redirecturi)
{
    var props = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirecturi };
    HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authorization.Challenge(props);
}
```

### 2 Direct navigation

If the user goes directly to a URL that's in need of auth, all you *should* need is to decorate it with the normal `[Authorize]` attribute.

### Background:

Seeing as one cannot (or don't want to) add every page under auth to the accept list of `redirect_uri`s in the identity provider, Microsoft adds this as metadata for the sigininsession using the OIDC `state` parameter. You won't probably see it directly, as it's being urlencoded internally with everything else you pass it (see `AuthenticationProperties`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually have only scenario 2, because whole application is accessible for authenticated user only. And custom authorize attribute is already in place globally for application.
So that, first I still need to find out how to pass current URL from angular to OWIN middleware to force it pass dynamic current URL instead of configured static one to IdentityServer in redirect_uri query string parameter..

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved my day!
I've used scenario 1.